# C - Reading string from a file. Getting random characters

Tags: c, string, file, printing

This program is designed to read from a file and print what is read to the screen (Then it accepts another word, don't know if this is relevant).

```
FILE *dataMarking;
int x=0, y=0, letters, score;
char scanWord[10][20], currentWord[10][20], scanDescription1[10][40], scanDescription2[10][40], scanDescription3[10][40];

dataMarking = fopen("marking.dat", "r");

if (dataMarking == NULL){page=99;}

else{

x=0;
while (fscanf(dataMarking, "%s:%s:%s:%s\n", scanWord[x], scanDescription1[x], scanDescription2[x], scanDescription3[x]) == 2){x++;};

fclose(dataMarking);

x=0;
while(x<10){
    printf("%s\n",scanDescription1[x]);
    printf("%s\n",scanDescription2[x]);
    printf("%s\n",scanDescription3[x]);
    scanf("%s",currentWord[x]);
    x++;}
```

Once printed to screen I get a random series of characters instead of the writing expected.
Above is the code used; below is the information in the file.

```
one:The number 1:skip:skip
two:The number 2:skip:skip
three:The number 3:skip:skip
four:The number 4:skip:skip
five:The number 5:skip:skip
six:The number 6:skip:skip
seven:The number 7:skip:skip
eight:The number 8:skip:skip
nine:The number 9:skip:skip
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fscanf returns the number of arguments parsed successfully. 
There are four arguments to fscanf not two. Your loop will fail on the first iteration because fscanf does not return 2.

```
while (fscanf(dataMarking, "%s:%s:%s:%s\n", scanWord[x], scanDescription1[x], scanDescription2[x], scanDescription3[x]) == 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably like this,

```
x=0;
while (fscanf(dataMarking, "%[^:]:%[^:]:%[^:]:%[^\n]%*c", scanWord[x], scanDescription1[x], scanDescription2[x], scanDescription3[x]) == 4){x++;}

fclose(dataMarking);

for(y=0;y<x;++y){
    printf("%s\n",scanDescription1[y]);
    printf("%s\n",scanDescription2[y]);
    printf("%s\n",scanDescription3[y]);
    printf("%s\n",scanWord[y]);
}
```